# How can i convert a string in a python method?

Tags: python

I receive a string, for example "save". And i have a method save with paramethers.
How can i convert the string save in a call to save().
I tried with eval and exec.

Edit: Solved here --> [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: "*I tried with eval and exec*" and then what happened?

Comment: don't use eval or exec.  use `getattr` on the object which has the method.

Comment: Where's this "save" string coming from? User input? If so, you're not going to want code that directly calls the method with that name. What happens if you want to change the user interface? Do you rename your method "s" if the save command becomes "s"? What if it's "Save Your Progress"?

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_method(self):
    save_method = getattr(self, 'save')
    save_method()  # save()
```